# Multiple BLE profiles

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

Is it possible to setup multiple BLE profiles using Bluez, for use in a single connection?

For example to allow a device to support a GATT profile and also use a PAN network access profile simultaneously.

Thanks

**Update:**

Thanks for the comment.
What I'm trying to achieve is an embedded device which connects to a phone app over BLE.

This connection will support a GATT protocol for accessing attributes on the device, but also BLE tethering so that the device has a direct internet connection through the phone. And both will work simultaneously.

Comment: Aren't all connected devices part of PAN? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible. PAN profile and GATT are not depend on each other.